# How to map api request dynamically in azure api management

Tags: azure, api, http, azure-devops, azure-api-management

I want to setup api management gateway which redirects to some backend url with the path which is there in url. which policy should i use for that?

request are like e.g.-

- GET https://something.azure-api.net/api/v1/getA
- GET https://something.azure-api.net/api/v2/getB/C
- POST ..../api/v1/putD
- 
- 

and so on....

it forwards to some backend like  e.g.-

- GET http://example.org/api/v1/getA
- GET http://exmaple.org/api/v2/getB/C
- POST ..../api/v1/putD
- 
- 

and so on....

Basically I want to pass the uri path(/api/v1/getA) to the backend as it is in the request.

Main requirement is-
**I have multiple paths in request and want to map them dyanmically in the backend.**

I'm tring using

````xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <set-backend-service base-url="http://example.org/" />
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>```
````

Comment: Please have a look at Azure Front door https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-redirect?pivots=front-door-standard-premium

Answer (score 0):

**Update for the updated question:**

It's not possible to do dynamic routing based on paths.

1. GET https://something.azure-api.net/api/v1/getA
2. GET https://something.azure-api.net/api/v1/getB/C
3. GET https://something.azure-api.net/api/v1/putD
4. POST https://something.azure-api.net/api/v1/putD

All 4 cases are 4 different operations in API Management.

---

**Former answer**

Based on your description you have

an API called `api`
with two versions
`v1` and `v2`.

[image]

Please use the [rewrite-uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/rewrite-uri-policy) policy to add the path.
Example:

```xml
<rewrite-uri template="/v2/US/hardware/{storenumber}&{ordernumber}?City=city&State=state" />
```

API `api` with version `v1` has one operation:
`**.azure-api.net/api/v1/getA`

To forward the request to `http://example.org/api/v1/getA`, the following policy is required:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service base-url="http://example.org/" />
        <rewrite-uri template="getA" copy-unmatched-params="true" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

[image]

API `api` with version `v2` has one operation:

`**.azure-api.net/api/v2/getB/C`

To forward the request to `http://example.org/api/v2/getB/C`, the following policy is required:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service base-url="http://example.org/" />
        <rewrite-uri template="getB/C" copy-unmatched-params="true" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

[image]

Comment: Here I have 100 api(s), and much more api will be there in future, so I don't want to manually add particular paths in the api management